# mvn spring-boot:run with loader.path in ZIP layout (PropertiesLauncher)

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

We have a spring boot project which are packaging in ZIP layout and supplying external jars using loader.path in java -jar as `java -Dloader.path=file:///jarfilepath -jar myproject.jar`.
But we also need to make it work with mvn spring-boot:run.
loader.path doesnt seem to work with it.
how can we do that ?